# Get a pop up every time a user selects another value in a dropdown list with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

the following  code gives me an alert with the selected value on page load

```
var itemLevel = $('Select[title=Item Level] option:selected').text();
alert(itemLevel);
```

But how do I do it if the user selects another value in the dropdown list and I want a new pop up with that value instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var itemLevel = $('select[title="Item Level"] option:selected').val();
```

Or based on name:

```
var itemLevel = $('select[name*="DropDownChoice"] option:selected').val();
```

The `*=` means get select box in whose name there is `DropDownChoice` somewhere.

If you want to get the `text` of selected option instead, use `text()` instead of `val()` eg:

```
var itemLevel = $('select[name*="DropDownChoice"] option:selected').text();
```

**Update:**

You can do like this:

```
$('Select[title="Item Level"'].change(function(){
  alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
});
```